# Air for iOS avoiding Man in the Middle attacks

Tags: ios, security, ssl, air, man-in-the-middle

In Air for iOS, I'm trying to find a way to mark when a possible Man in the Middle attack has occurred.

By default, anytime you try to connect to an SSL site that has an invalid certificate, you get the error:

> "A secure connection with this site cannot be verified. Would you
>   still like to proceed?
>
> The certificate you are viewing does not match the name of the site
>   you are trying to view."

I don't want to display this prompt, just disable network functions after that.

I started off trying to use a network monitor, but it gives the prompt as does running a separate URL request to test the connection.

I finally came across the "SecureSocketMonitor" which seems to do what I need it to do when running through the Flash environment, but once I compile into an Air for iOS application, it doesn't seem to function at all.

Does anyone know how I can detect an invalid SSL certificate without displaying that prompt?